# Change overview before publishing new project plan in MS Project

Tags: ms-project

recently we had issues with MS Project where people would make changes to one part of their project plan that would have an effect on other parts with out them noticing. Therefore I'd like to ask if there's a possibility (function, custom report,...) to compare the current plan in your client (before publishing) to the currently published version and highlighting any changes to the plan that will result from pressing  "publish".

Answer (score 0):

There is an Application Event called ProjectBeforePublish. With this you should be able to write a macro that copies all of the existing finish dates to a custom date field each time you publish the project. Then you can have a custom number field that calculates the difference between the last published data and the current finish.

By filtering on this variance field you should be able to see the impact of any changes throughout the project prior to publishing.